# PrimeNg datatable Multiple column Filtering

Tags: angular, primeng, primeng-datatable

I'm using PrimeNg datatable and i want to use multi columns filtering(server side).
Now It is working perfect with server side individual column filtering.

I found alot but didn't find much. Please help me out.

Thanks in advance